# React js history.push is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React.js and in this I want to create a simple login app, so after the login is success, I want to update state value in Parent component and redirect to other page using `history.push`. But here I have a problem because `push` is undefined.

I plan to use the state value of isLoggedIn to hide some element before the user login.

Here is the code in Home.jsx

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
  };

  handleIsLoggedIn = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: value,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <div className="navigation">
            <img src="../../drawable/jdl_logo.png" />
            <Link to="/member-list">Member</Link>
            <Link to="/override-list">Override</Link>
            <Link to="/">Login</Link>
          </div>
          <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Login onLogin={() => this.handleIsLoggedIn()} />} />
          <Route path="/member-list" component={MemberDashboard} />
          <Route path="/override-list" component={OverrideDashboard} />
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how to handle login in Login.jsx

```
loginUser = () => {
  Axios.post("http://private-6fdd31-intern1.apiary-mock.com/interns/login", this.state.user).then(
    (res) => {
      if (res.data.role === "admin") {
        this.onSuccessLogIn();
        this.props.history.push("/member-list");
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
};

onSuccessLogIn = () => {
  this.props.onLogin(true);
};
```

Comment: Are you passing `history` as a prop to Login.jsx?

Comment: @UtsavPatel yeah, I dont know about how to passing it in props, alrady found the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Login` isn't receiving the `history` prop from `Route`.

You can either pipe it through via the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props):

```
<Route
  path="/"
  exact
  component={
    routeProps => <Login {...routeProps} onLogin={this.handleIsLoggedIn} />
  }
/>
```

Or you can wrap `Login` with the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC and default export it for useage.